# remove text after final period in string

Tags: r, regex

I have a `grep` puzzle that's eluding me: I'd like to remove the text following the final period in a collection of strings (i am using R, so `perl` syntax is available).

For example, say the string is `ABCD.txt` this `grep` would return `ABCD`, and if the text was `abc.com.foo.bar`, it would return `abc.com.foo`.

Any help greatfully appreciated (i don't think i can drink any more coffee!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few solutions:

```
sub("^(.*)[.].*", "\\1", "abc.com.foo.bar") # 1
## [1] "abc.com.foo"

library(tools)
file_path_sans_ext("abc.com.foo.bar") # 3
## [1] "abc.com.foo"
```

ADDED. Regarding your comment asking to remove leading periods, simplest is to just feed this into any of the above where `x` is the input string:

```
sub("^[.]*", "", x)
```

To do any of them in one line:

```
x <- c("abc.com.foo.bar", ".abc.com.foo.bar", ".vimrc")

sub("^[.]*(.*)[.]?.*$", "\\1", x) # 1a
## [1] "abc.com.foo.bar" "abc.com.foo.bar" "vimrc"          

file_path_sans_ext(sub("^[.]*", "", x))
## [1] "abc.com.foo" "abc.com.foo" "vimrc"
```

Comment: is it too much to ask for a version that also trims leading periods? such that `.vimrc` becomes `vimrc`? (sorry, i didn't realise this case until you solved my major problem).

Comment: add `\\.` after the `^`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Thanks for another opportunity to upvote your insightful contributions. You taught me most of what I know about R-regex by way of your many postings to Rhelp.

Comment: @Justin -- thanks so much. working perfectly now. wish i'd asked earlier.

Comment: why do you show an example with `abc.foo.bar` (#2)? it's definitly not what OP want (and actually it's useless for everyone)

Comment: `sub("(.*[^.])[.][^.]+", "\\1", "abc.com.foo.bar")`, more readable I think.

Comment: @Justin -- i have another corner case: `.abc.com` ... i'd like to have `abc` returned. is this possible in one regex? atm i'm using two linked with an if statement.

Comment: @ricardo, have provided some additional code to address your leading string query.

Answer (score 3):

And a non-regex answer for no reason whatsoever:

```
test <- c("abc.com.foo.bar","ABCD.txt")
sapply(strsplit(test,"\\."), function(x) paste0(head(x,-1),collapse=".") )
#[1] "abc.com.foo" "ABCD"
```

Comment: To be completely accurate this is a simpler regex rather than a non-regex solution as `"\\."` is a regex.  Using `strsplit(test, ".", fixed = TRUE)` would be a non-regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub` for example like this:

```
sub('(.*)[.](.*)','\\1',c('abc.com.foo.bar','ABCD.txt'))
[1] "abc.com.foo" "ABCD"
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you with r and I almost forgot perl, but this works both in JS ([proof](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/wt9yT/)) and PHP

```
/\.[A-Za-z]+$/     -->    replace this with empty string ""
  ^    ^    ^
  |    |    |
  |    |    end of line
  |    only chars (you can add 0-9 if numbers are also present)
  dot before last chars
```

the syntax of regex is rather common, so I'm sure you can adopt it (maybe just get rid of `/`)