# remove initial period and text after final period in string

Tags: regex, r

I have a `regex` edge case that I am unable to solve. I need to `grep` to remove the leading period (if it exists) and the text following the last period (if it exists) from a string.

That is, given a vector:

```
x <- c("abc.txt", "abc.com.plist", ".abc.com")
```

I'd like to get the output:

```
[1] "abc"     "abc.com" "abc"
```

The first two cases are solved already I obtained help in [**this related question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847189/remove-text-after-final-period-in-string). However not for the third case with leading `.`

I am sure it is trivial, but i'm not making the connections.

Comment: it's not actually a duplicate as the answers do not solve the case `.abc.com` to `abc` ... i wish that they did. perhaps i've made some error copying, and if so i'll delete this qn -- please advise

Comment: I just realised that. Here's one that'll do as expected: `sub("^[.]*(.*)[.].*$", "\\1", x)`. I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, but I still think this could be reasonably incorporated into the other question.

Comment: Thomas, I agree, although he has left a comment and had no answer. I don't blame him. But @ricardo, link to the other question and say why you dont find the answer complete or how this question is different from that one to avoid such confusions.

Comment: I have edited to reflect the edge case and have linked to the other qn. thanks folks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex does what you want:

```
^\.+|\.[^.]*$
```

Replace its matches with the empty string.

In R:

```
gsub("^\\.+|\\.[^.]*$", "", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Anchor the match to the start of the string
\.+    # and match one or more dots
|      # OR
\.     # Match a dot
[^.]*  # plus any characters except dots
$      # anchored to the end of the string.
```

Comment: `perl=TRUE` is not strictly necessary here, though it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: +1 / accepted. thanks very much -- that's perfect. Also, i really appreciate you making the effort to add the explanation. I'm in the steepest part of the regex learning curve.