# R: Remove end of text after matching string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I would like to remove any text that appears after a certain character match either `THE END` or `FINIS`. I know this is very similar to this other [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847189/remove-text-after-final-period-in-string), but I am just not skilled enough in regex to make this work for me.

My text is Shakespear books taken from Project Gutenberg. They typically look something like

```
txt <- "... thou hast tam'd a curst shrow.   LUCENTIO. 'Tis a wonder, 
  by your leave, she will be tam'd so. Exeunt  THE END   <<THIS ELECTRONIC  VERSION OF THE 
  COMPLETE WORKS OF WILLIAM ..."
```

or

```
txt <- "... thou hast tam'd a curst shrow.   LUCENTIO. 'Tis a wonder, 
  by your leave, she will be tam'd so. Exeunt  FINIS  <<THIS ELECTRONIC  VERSION OF THE 
  COMPLETE WORKS OF WILLIAM ..."
```

My ideal would look something like `gsub("^[THE END]*|^[FINIS]*", "", txt)` returning `"... thou hast tam'd a curst shrow.   LUCENTIO. 'Tis a wonder,   by your leave, she will be tam'd so. Exeunt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close to do it, you have to use:

```
gsub("(THE END|FINIS).*", "", txt)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ9wU7/1)**

Btw, as [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496803/thelatemail) pointed in his comment with `sub` would be enough for one replacement.

Comment: `sub` should be enough, as there is only one replacement.