# Convert nested list elements into data frame and bind the result into one data frame

Tags: r

I have a nested lists like this :

```
x <- list(x = list(a = 1, 
                   b = 2), 
          y = list(a = 3, 
                   b = 4))
```

And I would like to convert the nested list into data.frames and then bind all data frames into one.

For this level of nesting I can do it with this line :

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(x, as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

So the result is :

```
  a b
x 1 2
y 3 4
```

My problem is that I would like to achieve that regardless of the level of nesting. Another example with this list :

```
x <- list(X = list(x = list(a = 1, 
                       b = 2), 
              y = list(a = 3, 
                       b = 4)),
     Y = list(x = list(a = 1, 
                       b = 2), 
              y = list(a = 3, 
                       b = 4)))

do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(x, function(x) do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(x, as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))))

    a b
X.x 1 2
X.y 3 4
Y.x 1 2
Y.y 3 4
```

Does anyone has an idea to generelized this to any level of nesting ?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Is there any guarantee about the structure of the input list? Will it always have the leafs containing the same number of elements? Can we count on it always being 2 columns in the output? Or will that possibly be different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Borrowing from Spacedman and flodel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432863/determine-level-of-nesting-in-r), we can define the following pair of recursive functions:

```
library(tidyverse)  # I use dplyr and purrr here, plus tidyr further down below

depth <- function(this) ifelse(is.list(this), 1L + max(sapply(this, depth)), 0L)

bind_at_any_depth <- function(l) {
  if (depth(l) == 2) {
    return(bind_rows(l))
  } else {
    l <- at_depth(l, depth(l) - 2, bind_rows)
    bind_at_any_depth(l)
  }
}
```

We can now bind any arbitrary depth list into a single data.frame:

```
bind_at_any_depth(x)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 × 2
>       a     b
>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1     2
> 2     3     4
> ```

```
bind_at_any_depth(x_ext) # From P Lapointe
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 × 2
>       a     b
>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1     2
> 2     5     6
> 3     7     8
> 4     1     2
> 5     3     4
> ```

If you want to keep track of the origin of each row, you can use this version:

```
bind_at_any_depth2 <- function(l) {
  if (depth(l) == 2) {
    l <- bind_rows(l, .id = 'source')
    l <- unite(l, 'source', contains('source'))
    return(l)
  } else {
    l <- at_depth(l, depth(l) - 2, bind_rows, .id = paste0('source', depth(l)))
    bind_at_any_depth(l)
  }
}
```

This will add a `source` column:

```
bind_at_any_depth2(x_ext)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 × 3
>   source     a     b
> *  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1  X_x_1     1     2
> 2  X_y_z     5     6
> 3 X_y_zz     7     8
> 4  Y_x_1     1     2
> 5  Y_y_1     3     4
> ```

**Note**: At some point you can use `purrr::depth`, and will need to change `at_depth` to `modify_depth` when their new version rolls out to CRAN (thanks @ManuelS).

Comment: You should mention that `purrr::depth()` is part of the development version of `purrr` and that `modify_depth()` will eventually replace `at_depth()`. otherwise: great answer

Comment: @ManuelS, Actually, I was unaware of that. Thanks! I was using the `depth` function as defined at the start of my code (borrowed from the QA linked).

Comment: oh i see. I overlooked that part and assumed you are using the `purrr::depth()` function. Probably makes sense to use that version although your function probably does the same

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Here's a way to flatten more deeply nested lists simply with `unlist`. Since the structure is now uneven, the result will not be a `data.frame`.

```
x_ext <- list(X = list(x = list(a = 1,
                       b = 2),
              y = list(z=list(a = 5,
                       b = 6),
                       zz=list(a = 7,
                       b = 8))),
     Y = list(x = list(a = 1,
                       b = 2),
              y = list(a = 3,
                       b = 4)))

unlist(x_ext)

   X.x.a    X.x.b  X.y.z.a  X.y.z.b X.y.zz.a X.y.zz.b    Y.x.a    Y.x.b    Y.y.a    Y.y.b 
       1        2        5        6        7        8        1        2        3        4
```

My initial answer was `unlist` first and `rbind` aftrerwards. However, it works only with the example in the question.

```
x_unlist <- unlist(x, recursive = FALSE)
do.call("rbind", x_unlist)
    a b
X.x 1 2
X.y 3 4
Y.x 1 2
Y.y 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten and coerce to a data.frame while collecting names with `purrr::flatten_df` from [the development version](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/):

```r
library(purrr)    # or library(tidyverse)

x <- list(X = list(x = list(a = 1, 
                       b = 2), 
              y = list(a = 3, 
                       b = 4)),
     Y = list(x = list(a = 1, 
                       b = 2), 
              y = list(a = 3, 
                       b = 4)))

x %>% flatten_df(.id = 'var')
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>     var     a     b
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     x     1     2
#> 2     y     3     4
#> 3     x     1     2
#> 4     y     3     4
```

or if you want to save both sets of names, `map_df`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x %>% map_df(~bind_rows(.x, .id = 'var2'), .id = 'var1')
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>    var1  var2     a     b
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     X     x     1     2
#> 2     X     y     3     4
#> 3     Y     x     1     2
#> 4     Y     y     3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

This builds on P.Lapointe's answer and uses idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847189/remove-text-after-final-period-in-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774086/extracting-text-after-last-period-in-string-in-r) to extract the final names in the list.

```
 bind <- function(x) {
     s = stack(unlist(x))
     s$major = tools::file_path_sans_ext(s$ind)
     s$minor = tools::file_ext(s$ind)
     as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(data=s, values ~  major + minor))
 }

 bind(x)
    a b
X.x 1 2
X.y 3 4
Y.x 1 2
Y.y 3 4

 bind(x_ext)
       a b
X.x    1 2
X.y.z  5 6
X.y.zz 7 8
Y.x    1 2
Y.y    3 4
```

Answer (score -1):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% 
   map(bind_rows) %>%
   bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
# A tibble: 4 × 3
#     grp     a     b    
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     X     1     2
#2     X     3     4
#3     Y     1     2
#4     Y     3     4
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, do.call(c, x))
#    a b
#X.x 1 2
#X.y 3 4
#Y.x 1 2
#Y.y 3 4
```

Comment: Your base answer only works with the second example.